# The Popup window cannot function on Marker

Tags: android, popupwindow, marker

good morning

At here i am try to add popup window function on a marker click but when i launching my app, the popup is not function.
and i am try to solve it but still cannot solve the problem.

this is my java code

```
package com.everstudio.nadejenew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;

public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

static View view;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private RelativeLayout dialog_popup;
Marker m1;

public LocationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng location = new LatLng(2.1895696, 102.2478482);


    m1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Location"));


    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker Marker) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismissbtn);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }});
            return true;
        }

    });
}

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView);`